# Load a view from a controller and load the views original controller too

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to load a different view in a controller (not the default view)

the different view is loaded but I have some code in the controller that originally belongs to the view.

The original Controller isn't loaded when displaying the view.
Does CakePHP have a solution for this?

To make thing clear I created a scheme:
[image]

Who can help me with this?

Comment: Move the part that you want from B to A controller and put it before the loading of the B-view...

Comment: Controller B and View B is used on a lot of different pages and are always the same. Controller A is unique

Comment: You shouldn't be calling actions from another controller. It breaks the MVC structure. What is the sense of calling controller A, then controller B and then its view? Why don't you use redirection or something similar instead?

Comment: I agree with Steve. I think you need to refactor some code from B to an handler or something so that you can use it in controller A.

Comment: @Ross, Using a component is a good idea. Going to test this. Thanks

Comment: @Ross The component idea worked. Thx

Comment: @Ross Please post your solution as a Anwser so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i agree with all of the comments saying that this breaks MVC.

Its possible using requestAction(). Its up to you, how you use it.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::requestAction

Comment: I created a component, I don't believe it breaks the MVC or does it? However, This works like a charm.

Comment: No, sharing components is in the spirit of MVC.